# Remove the Active class from relevant sections

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to write a code that will only remove the active class from the current section, not from the other. But my code is removing the active class from other sections as well. What I am doing wrong here?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".nav li button").click(function(){
      $(".nav li button").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.nav{ margin:0 0 15px; padding:0; list-style:none; }
.nav li{ display:inline-block; }
.nav li button.active{ background:green; color:#fff;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-container">
  <ul class="nav">
      <li><button>Button 1</button></li>
      <li><button>Button 2</button></li>
      <li><button>Button 3</button></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav">
      <li><button>Button 1</button></li>
      <li><button>Button 2</button></li>
      <li><button>Button 3</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can directly define a .active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `ul` refer to current section then use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find all `li button` inside it and remove `active` class from them:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".nav li button").click(function(){
      $(this).closest('ul').find('li button').removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.nav{ margin:0 0 15px; padding:0; list-style:none; }
.nav li{ display:inline-block; }
.nav li button.active{ background:green; color:#fff;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-container">
  <ul class="nav">
      <li><button>Button 1</button></li>
      <li><button>Button 2</button></li>
      <li><button>Button 3</button></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav">
      <li><button>Button 1</button></li>
      <li><button>Button 2</button></li>
      <li><button>Button 3</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```